# Make multiple buttons in one window. Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make 4 buttons in one window, aligned as showed in the picture below. I have made the first button, the "big button", but It will center itself and I want it to be in the left upper corner and to make a easy FX program that can place these buttons as in this picture:

[image]

Here is some edited code . I am almost happy!

package sample;

public class Main extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    //lager top meny stor knapp
    HBox topMenu = new HBox();
    Button a = new Button("Stor knapp");
    a.setPrefSize(120,30);

    topMenu.getChildren().addAll(a);

    //lager venstre del
    HBox left = new HBox();
    Button en = new Button("Venstre knapp!");
    Button to = new Button("Hoyre knapp!");

    left.getChildren().addAll(en,to);

    //lager høyre del
    VBox right = new VBox();
    Button button3 = new Button("Vbox knapp 1!");
    Button button4 = new Button("Vbox knapp 2!");
    right.getChildren().addAll(button3,button4);

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setTop(topMenu);
    borderPane.setLeft(left);
    borderPane.setRight(right);




    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 300,300);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a StackPane everything you add to that pane will be centred and on top of each other.

For the layout you are aiming for you will need a GridPane combined with VBox and HBox. Take a look at [this overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) of layouts.

Comment: I see, but I do not manage to do this myself. Anyone wants to make this little window with the 4 buttons?

Comment: Please study the linked resource and try harder petter.  This is fairly basic layout setup, the understanding of which is mandatory for anybody trying to create any kind of non-trivial application using JavaFX.  You will learn more from studying the relevant documentation and further work on building the application yourself than by somebody supplying you a pre-built solution.